# To what functions does $f(t):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-t\sqrt{n}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $f(t):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-t\sqrt{n}}$ for $t>0.$ Are there elementary functions that have precisely this series representation? Obviously this functions needs to have a pole at $t=0$ and is not represented by this series for $t>0.$

Comment: For large values of $t$, it seems to be close to $e^{e^{-t}}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: How did you come up with that?

Comment: @MrYouMath. Just plotting the values of $\log(\log(f))$ as a function of $t$ first.

Comment: Due to the $\sqrt{n}$ in the exponential it does not look like a series that have an elementary closed form. The higher order terms is the series go to zero very rapidly when $t>0$ so just keeping the first few, e.g. $1 + e^{-t}$, should give a good approximation for large $t$. This could also explain the closeness to $e^{e^{-t}} \approx 1 + e^{-t}$ noted in the comments above.

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form.  Do you assert there is a **pole** at $t=0$ or merely that $f(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to 0$?  Comparing to the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-t\sqrt{x}}\;dx = \frac{2}{t^2}$, we get $\frac{2}{t^2} < f(t) < 1+\frac{2}{t^2}$, which does suggest a **pole**.